# How can I get rows 1 through n (as a subquery) where n is value in one column in main query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How can I get generated rows from 1 to n (as a subquery) where n is a value in one field in main query in SQL Server?

the output should be like this:

for n=2 then the generated rows must be:
    1
    2

for n=5 then the generated rows must be:
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5

Best regards.

Comment: @BalaYesu Chilakalapudi: please use `code markdown` sparingly. "1 through n" is not code, and should not be in code markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'select TOP 1 column from table ORDER By column desc' for your sub query to arrange the biggest value first then get the first row

Comment: thank you for your response but that is not what Iam looking for. I rephrased my Q I hope you get my point. regards

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need 5 records, then you can use:

Select Top 5 * from [table]